# ListPlot of auto-correlation function pushes data 1 lag

Tags: plotting, functions, time-series

I'm trying to plot a graph of a sample autocorrelation function at different lags.
The code I'm using is

```
ListPlot[CorrelationFunction[adev, {20}], Filling -> Axis, 
 GridLines -> {None, {{2/Sqrt[Length[data]], 
     Dashed}, {-2/Sqrt[Length[data]], Dashed}}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Lags", "Autocorrelation"}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}]
```

And I get the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the ACF at lag zero is equal to one, but in the plot it shows as if it was at lag 1...

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you please give an example of how you generate `adev` and `data`?  When I set `adev = data = RandomFunction[ARProcess[{.2, .3, .4}, 1], {1, 10^4}]` as in the [CorrelationFunction documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CorrelationFunction.html), the lags look correct.

Comment: @Rashid data is imported directly from a file, and 'adev = Drop[Flatten[data], 1];'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample = RandomFunction[ARMAProcess[{-.3, .1}, {.4}, 1], {0, 100}];
data = sample["States"][[1]];
```

As observed by @Rashid, if the first argument of `CorrelationFunction` is a `TemporalData` object (like `sample`), everything work as expected:

```
ListPlot[CorrelationFunction[#, {20}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], FillingStyle -> Thick,
 PlotRangePadding -> .1, ImageSize -> 500, Filling -> Axis,
 GridLines -> {None, {{2/Sqrt[21], Dashed}, {-2/Sqrt[21], Dashed}}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Lags", "Autocorrelation"}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}]&;

 lpF[sample]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when the first argument of `CorrelationFunction` is list(s) of `y` values (as is the case with `data`), we get as the OP does

```
 lpF[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The reason for the difference is the fact that, when `x` coordinates are not explicit in the input, the sample space is taken to be `Range[1, Length@data]`

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

So using `DataRange->{0,20}` fixes the picture:

```
ListPlot[CorrelationFunction[data, {20}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], FillingStyle -> Thick,
 PlotRangePadding -> .1, ImageSize -> 500, Filling -> Axis, 
 DataRange -> {0, 20},
 GridLines -> {None, {{2/Sqrt[21], Dashed}, {-2/Sqrt[21], Dashed}}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Lags", "Autocorrelation"}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This issue does not arise with `sample` because, the `x` coordinates are explicitly given in the input to `ListPlot`:

```
CorrelationFunction[sample, {20}] // Normal
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

whereas, for `data` we have

```
CorrelationFunction[data, {20}] // Normal
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Many Thanks. Very complete answer ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.